# run-length encoding using C++

Tags: c++, compression, run-length-encoding

I have a text file with a string which I'd like to encode.

Let's say it is: `aaahhhhiii kkkjjhh ikl wwwwwweeeett`

and here is the code:

```
void Encode(std::string &inputstring, std::string &outputstring)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inputstring.length(); i++) {
        int count = 1;
        while (inputstring[i] == inputstring[i+1]) {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        if(count <= 1) {
            //std::cout << inputstring[i] << "";
            outputstring += inputstring[i];
            outputstring += "";
        } else {
            //std::cout << inputstring[i] << count;
            outputstring += inputstring[i];
            outputstring += count;
        }
    }
}
```

output should be: `3a4h3i 3k2j2h ikl 6w4e2t`

Characters or white spaces with less (or equal) than one character get just printed out - no change.

So far so good and code is working.. actually.

When I use `std::cout` in `if` and `else` - then it is showing me the output like above. So perfect.

BUT, I'd like to hand over the result to the parameters (`std::string &outputstring`) and print the result in the main method.

But it is printing ONLY the `if statement` not `else statement`.

Can someone help me with this matter?

Comment: ***Can someone help me with this matter?*** My word of advice is to learn to use your debugger. If you had set a breakpoint in the else you should have seen that it was called. Even using a cout could of helped as in this:  [https://ideone.com/ahDvox](https://ideone.com/ahDvox)

Comment: Also put `outputstring += inputstring[i];` after `outputstring += std::to_string(count);`

Comment: @drescherjm you are right. But I am still a beginner though. Sorry, but I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: I tell you this because its essential skill you will need to master to be an effective programmer. I debug regularly and I have programmed in `c++` since the 1990s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was with the line `outputstring += count;`. An integer is interpreted as a character code when assigning it to a  string. You don't want the character with the character code count, but you want to convert the number count to a string, so you should use `outputstring += std::to_string(count);`

Comment: holy sh##t.. this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man! I appreciate your help. Thanks!